# Is there a way to get ascii value of a string representing a special character?

Tags: c++, char, special-characters, lexer

I'm working on a compiler and I simply want to be able to read the literal `'\n'` as it's ascii value (`10`) in my language.

---

But there are actually more escape sequence like `\n` and I don't want to attempt to account for all of them by myself when C++ already is fully capable of that.

---

I basically need a way to take the array/string:

```cpp
const char* s1 = {'\\'/* a simple slash */, 'n', '\0'}; // "\\n"
std::string s2 = "\\x002b"; // {'\\', 'x', '0', '0', '2', 'b', '\0'}
```

and treat it as the C/C++ compiler would have.

---

I'd like a std functions to do it or if at runtime I could interact with the C++ compiler and let it do the job, something like this:

```cpp
char c1 = exec("'%s'", s1); // would return '\n' as one character (ascii 10)
char c2 = std::parse_char_literal(s2); // would return '+' (ascii 43)
```

Thanks.

Comment: there is no way to interact with the compiler the way you want. It doesn't exist at runtime. You have to parse the strings yourself.  For instance, you will have to manually translate the char sequence `'\' 'n'` into a numeric 10. Or `std::stoi()` can parse integers from hex-encoded strings, like `"0x002b"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after Remy Lebeau's comment and a rethink i decided to write my own code to handle most of the functionality of the C/C++ compiler.
Using the special characters table from [here](https://www.austincc.edu/rickster/COSC1320/handouts/escchar.htm) I decided to not implement special characters which are more than 1 character long because I'm lazy.
That leaves `\n \t \v \b \r \f \a \\ \? \' \" \0`.

---

That is my code:

```cpp
char escSeqToChar(std::string v)
{
    if (v[0] == '\\' && v.size() == 2)
    {
        switch (v[1])
        {
        case 'n':
            v = "\n"; break;
        case 't':
            v = "\t"; break;
        case 'v':
            v = "\v"; break;
        case 'b':
            v = "\b"; break;
        case 'r':
            v = "\r"; break;
        case 'f':
            v = "\f"; break;
        case 'a':
            v = "\a"; break;
        case '\\':
            v = "\\"; break;
        case '?':
            v = "\?"; break;
        case '\'':
            v = "\'"; break;
        case '\"':
            v = "\""; break;
        case '0':
            v = "\0"; break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    if (v.size() > 1) printf("ERROR_CHAR_TOO_LONG"); exit(-1);

    return v[0];
}
```